# Auto add scrollbar to div container if the content of the div exceeds the height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate the contents of the div from CMS. Everytime I fetch data from CMS, different size of data is retrieved. Based on the content size, I need to add the scroll bar to the div.

```
<div class = "container">
 <div id = "div1">
  <a>Div 1 Link1</a>
  <a>Div 1 Link 2</a>
  <a>Div 1 Link 3</a>
 </div>
 <div id = "div2">
  <a>Div 2 link 1</a>
  <a>Div 2 Link 2</a>
 </div>
 <div id = "div3">
  <a>Div 3 Link 1</a>
  <a>Div 3 Link 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Above is the code. If I add more Links in any div, scrollbar should appear.
I could achieve this in CSS. I want to know to achieve in JQuery.

Thanks in Adavnce

Comment: is there is an event that will occur when you adding each link?

Comment: something like `$(".container").css("overflow", "auto")`?

Comment: @Frebin francis. There is no such event.

Comment: In Css. I have done something like: overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:hidden;

Comment: @Archana so why do you want to do this using jquery ?